# Cap download size with Python requests library

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I'm crawling a bunch of web pages using Python's request library, but occasionally the crawler will stumble upon an absolutely mammoth page, be it a PDF or video or otherwise gargantuan file.  Is there a good way to limit the maximum size of file it will download?

Comment: You can check the content type in the headers and make sure it's not pdf or video or if it's anything like urllib2, you can tell the `read()` function the maximum amount of bytes to read: `urllib2.urlopen('htpp://page.com').read(1024)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The urlopen object has a method info() which gives all kinds of useful header information, including Content-Length

Occassionally this is not correctly set but should be in most cases and will help